# How to compute frequency of overlapping bins when you know bin width and frequency of each bin

Tags: distributions, frequency

I cannot understand the computation in the below article :
https://logological.org/girlfriend

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZM5wA.png)

The writer finds the number of girls aged 18 and above multiplying the number of girls in the bin "15-19" (39 560 000) by a fraction which I don't understand where it comes from.

My thought is that he uses the frequency density distribution n/Δx, where n is the frequency and Δx is the bin width. But how does he come up with the numerator and why add 1  on both numerator and denominator?is it because he wants to find frequency +1 year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set of women aged 15 to 19 in 1998 contains women of 5 distinct ages: 15, 16, 17, 18, and 19. 5 is 19 - 15 + 1 (the absolute-value signs aren't necessary if we subtract with the larger end first) rather than just 19 - 15 because the range is inclusive of its endpoints (we're avoiding a [fencepost error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error)).

The numerator corresponds to the set of women aged 18 to 21 in 2000, or equivalently, the set of women aged 16 to 19 in 1998. We get 21 - 18 + 1 by the same logic as above.

The smaller set is a subset of the larger set, so by dividing the set sizes, we get the probability that a variable distributed uniformly in the bigger set will land in the smaller set.

The final quotient is 4/5. In short, this is the right answer because the smaller set has 4 ages and the bigger set has 5.